# Combine arrays using indices

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to combine two arrays into one multi-dimensional array based on element indices. For example:

```
arr1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
arr2 = ["B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

should create

```
arr3 = [["A", "B"], ["B", "C"], ["C", "D"], ["D", "E"]]
```

That is, the nth element of `arr1` and `arr2` should form an array which is the nth element of `arr3`.

The arrays are the same length, so this is not a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a method, which does exactly that - [`Array#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```
arr1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
arr2 = ["B", "C", "D", "E"]
arr1.zip(arr2) # => [["A", "B"], ["B", "C"], ["C", "D"], ["D", "E"]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, but when I use `puts arr1.zip(arr2)`, it prints the elements of the nested arrays on separate lines, and using `print` prints everything on one continuous line. Is there any way to print each nested array on a new line?

Comment: Nevermind! I've resolved the above issue myself.

Comment: @ndn, it's considered bad form to prompt for points and having an answer selected. Compose well thought-out answers that are correct and the points will happen. Stack Overflow is about helping, not about gaming.

Comment: @theTinMan, I would disagree. It happens very often that newer users just get their answer and never return to the question again. It is also an issue as people that search for this question will have to try the answers/read further just because no answer was accepted, thus pointing to the fact that it worked for OP. It looks like the [community is fine with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer).

Comment: @theTinMan, basically, it helps newer users learn how to use the system, it also helps other people searching for the same thing.

Comment: That point is occasionally offered up, but consider whether it looks better for the person offering the answer to educate or for others of us who are totally neutral (without a horse in the race), and/or the system itself, to prompt them. The community watches and will help educate.

Comment: @theTinMan, let me ask it this way. There is obviously gain for me, for OP and for the community if I ask him to accept an answer (which by his words is what he was looking for), will it be mine or someone else's. Who and what benefits if I don't?

Comment: Gain for you? Because you got points? Or because you got recognized? What will you buy with the new points? New power? Worrying about points encourages worrying about the wrong things. If you want to encourage the OP, then answer, and if no answer is selected after a few days then a gentle nudge in the comments to the question itself will suffice. Suggesting your answer be accepted within the hour it was asked is overly eager considering one day had not passed. So, my point is, be patient, allow others to answer, and allow the the OP to wait and see if others answer and pick the best one.

Comment: @theTinMan, first of all, you didn't answer my question. Second of all, you grossly over-exaggerated everything. Anyone with any level of metacognition can understand that yes - some sort of statistic (will it be flat reputation, answer acceptance rate, people reached, etc) partially serves as positive reinforcement. This doesn't disqualify people's willingness to help for the sake of helping. Wait for what? Someone to answer a closed question? A question, which unlike other questions, actually has *a* correct answer. And this answer was just given. Who benefits from waiting in this situation?

Comment: Ok guys, I think this went a tad off topic :) Sorry I forgot to mark the answer, I left to quickly do something else and completely forgot about it when I came back. I've marked your answer as correct.